# Medalha Capelo concedida "injustamente", há como reverter?

Tags: suporte, medalhas

No dia 17/04 esta medalha me [foi concedida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/41/mortarboard?userid=28595), só que o que resultou em sua concessão foi que algum usuário saiu votando em minhas respostas de uma vez só(isto pode ser visto na imagem abaixo), e o sistema entendeu que era válido e concedeu a medalha. Porém, a reputação ganha(200 pra ser mais preciso), foi totalmente revertida em virtude do "serial upvote", mas a medalha continua.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Há alguma forma de reverter também sua concessão, uma vez que a reputação necessário para ganhá-la naquele dia foi revertida? Gosto das coisas corretas, mesmo que seja apenas uma medalha simbólica.

Comment: Até onde eu sei ela foi ganha de forma justa, dentro dos critérios. Uma remoção seria feita se fosse detectada uma fraude, o que não parece ter ocorrido. O ganho parece ser legítimo pelos critérios atuais. Então não sei se pode removê-la manualmente. O que pode-se pensar é debater o critério de não perder a medalha em um caso assim. Acho que já foi debatido no metão e preferiram deixar assim, o que eu concordo, BTW.

Comment: @bigown houve uma reversão, então não foi de forma justa, senão os 200 rep não seriam retirados pelo sistema. A consequência disso foi a medalha, que foi dada alguns minutos após a soma ser alcançada. O sistema reverteu algumas horas após, mas a medalha pemaneceu.

Comment: Se está escrito na regra que é assim, é justa :P

Comment: A regra é clara. **Ganhou 200 ou mais pontos de reputação (o limite diário) em um dia..**. Brincadeiras a parte, eu não me preocuparia com isso. Você não fez nada de errado, e atingiu o limite. A meu ver você mereceu.

Comment: Acho que o problema real são os que obtiveram essa medalha por meio de manipulação de votos e ainda assim [aparecem nesta lista](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/41/mortarboard)

Answer (score 8):

*Conforme pesquisei:*

- [Why are badges kept, even if pertinent action is reversed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58389/198279)
- [How do "badges" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17853/198279)

> Tentei retirar a parte importante:

A administração Stack Exchange tem afirmado que as medalhas "regulares" (aquelas que ganhou por alguma atividade no site, ou seja que exclui as medalhas "especiais") nunca são removidas, a menos que elas tenham sido obtidas por engano "hediondo".

Comportamento que qualifica como "hediondo" é definido em uma base para cada caso, por exemplo:

- Usando multiplas contas para ganhar upvotes na conta principal, como por exemplo manipular para ganhar a medalha [Luminar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/117/illuminator) ou [Pergunta legal](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/20/nice-question) qualifica como "hediondo".
- Dar downvote em algo e remover em seguida, apenas para obter a medalha [Critico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/7/critic) é algo que **não** é considerado "hediondo".

  > Todavia medalhas sobre tags podem ser removidas se você der muitos downvotes o que pode afetar os requisitos para este tipo de medalha

Então medalhas "regulares",  uma vez obtidos ficarão para "sempre". Mesmo se os critérios pelos quais você ganhou um medalha mudaram (o post foi apagado, você tem downvoted, etc.).

> Se me equivoquei na tradução por favor aponte o problema, obrigado

### Resumindo

Medalhas são para sempre em sua conta, somente **medalhas especificas** e a pessoa tendo ganho por **manipulação própria** que provavelmente serão removidas.

O seu caso não foi uma manipulação sua, mas sim um *serial-upvote* que de certa forma gostou de alguma ajuda que você deu e achou que você merecia ser recompensado.

No caso você não fez nada, então a medalha fica ;)

Comment: Apesar de ter entendido a resposta eu não concordo com as medalhas regulares serem assim "para sempre" até para estes casos como o meu. Apesar de não ter culpa do que ocorreu, eu não tive esforço pra ganhá-la. Mas já que não adianta remar contra a maré ne, o jeito e deixar ela quieta la mesmo. :/ PS.: Obrigado pelos esclarecimentos :)

Comment: @diegofm não concorda com a resposta ou com a funcionalidade do site?

Comment: Não concordo com a forma como a SE trata esse tipo de coisa. A resposta está ótima, me esclareceu perfeitamente sobre o caso :D

Comment: @diegofm fui eu que li errado kkkkk, então cá entre nós apenas, mas eu acho que são funcionalidades complexas de serem implementadas, ou seja precisariam criar uma ferramentas para reversão que fosse controlada, tanto que muitas coisas no site demoram a "computar". Então se a minha opinião valesse como resposta, seria algo como *"Não foi implementado completamente, ou por dificuldade ou por tempo ou por não acharem necessário"*

Comment: Eu editei o primeiro comentário pra ficar mais claro com o que eu não concordava, estava confuso mesmo, você não leu errado kkkk